# Why does the cursor jump to end of the input when using react-input-mask along with formik?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, formik

I am trying to use `react-input-mask` along with `formik` to mask an input. I have used this masked input outside of `formik` and it worked as expected, but with `formik` the values in the input are not getting updated, and the cursor keeps jumping to the end of the input.

Here is a [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-firefly-4yfsc) to see the issue and code in action.

Here is the code at a glance.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import Inputmask from "react-input-mask";
import Yup from "yup";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      dob: ""
    }
  });
  return (
    <Inputmask
      type="text"
      name="dob"
      mask="00-00-0000"
      alwaysShowMask
      onChange={formik.handleChange}
      value={formik.values.dob}
      onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
    />
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Everything looks ok at a glance, you'd have to look at the ```InputMask``` source and trace exactly what it's doing with those props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you're not declaring your mask correctly. If you want to have only numbers the way to declare the mask is by using the number `9`. In your case you would declare the `mask` props as follows:

`mask="99-99-9999"`

see the docs here
https://github.com/sanniassin/react-input-mask#mask

and see working code sandbox here
https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-sea-hve91